# WPF Databinding DataTrigger to change color of shape based on boolean value

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatrigger

I am trying to change the color of a shape by means of databinding and data trigger.

But i am still new to WPF and all.

Let me illustrate with an example. this is a group box

```
<GroupBox x:Class="Server.Host.SingleAxisControls"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:host="clr-namespace:Server.Host"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignWidth="200">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="180" >
            <host:MyRectangleControl x:Name="MyRectangle" />
            <Button Click="OnButton_Click" Width="80" Margin="20,5,20,5">On</Button>
            <Button Click="OffButton_Click" Width="80">Off</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</GroupBox>
```

MyRectangleControl is a usercontrol of something like

```
<UserControl x:Class="Server.Host.MyRectangleControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="30" d:DesignWidth="30">
<Grid>
    <Rectangle  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              Height="25"
              Margin="0,0,0,0"
              Stroke="Black"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Width="25" 
              Fill="red">
        <Rectangle.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Test,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                 Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Fill"
                                Value="Green" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Rectangle.Style>
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

In the code behind the groupbox, I have something like

```
namespace Server.Host
{
public partial class SingleAxisControls : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public SingleAxisControls()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MyRectangle.DataContext = this;
    }

    private bool _test;
    public bool Test
    {
        get { return _test; }
        set
        {
            _test = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Test"));
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Test = true;
    }

    private void OffButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Test = false;
    }
}
```

I am not sure what is wrong but it doesn't seem change the color of the rectangle when i change the value of test from false to true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a problem of [value precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

When you set a DependencyProperty directly in the declaration of an Element this value has higher precedence than a value set in a style.

All you have to do is set the Fill property to Red in the Style:

```
<Rectangle  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          Height="25"
          Margin="0,0,0,0"
          Stroke="Black"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          Width="25" 
          >
    <Rectangle.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Test,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Fill"
                            Value="Green" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Rectangle.Style>
</Rectangle>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another valid option is writing a converter to the binding. It would look like this:

```
class BooleanToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,  System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if ((bool)value)
            {
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            }
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

(You can set the colors to anything you want)
and the Xaml would look like this:

```
<Rectangle  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              Height="25"
              Margin="0,0,0,0"
              Stroke="Black"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Width="25" 
              Fill="{Binding Test, Converter={StaticResource b2b}}">
```

with this at the top of your xaml:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <BooleanToBrushConverter x:Key="b2b" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Note: if your converter is in a different location you will need to include it in the namespace and preface the declaration with whatever you named the namespace i.e.

```
xlmns:converters="clr-namespace:Project.Converters"
```

in the `<UserControl>` tag
and then `<converters: BooleanToBrushConverter x:Key="b2b" />` in the resources